# Pygame shapes cannot take non integer arguments

Tags: python, pygame, physics

Does it matter that in the Pygame module, the shapes cannot take float values as their arguments?

This is raised due to the fact that I am currently making a relatively basic physics simulation, and using pygame to do the graphics, and in a physics simulation, it rarely/never happens that an object is centred such that it has an integer value.

I am wondering mainly if this would have a significant effect on the accuracy of the simulation?

Comment: I usually store the actual positions of my objects in [`pygame.math.Vector2`s](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2), because `pygame.Rect`s can't store floating point numbers and that leads to inaccurate movement. You can pass a Vector2 to `pygame.Surface.blit` or assign it to a rect, but if you want to use it for example with `pygame.draw.circle` you have to convert the vector to ints first.

Comment: I am only using Pygame for graphics, as I wanted to learn myself about making (vector and general) classes and implement them into the engine. Therefore, if I just round the values to the nearest whole number, when displaying the object, yet use the exact values for further calculations, would that be accurate enough? MY reasoning is due to the fact that the arguments that those shapes take is their position in pixels, and so when displaying, if it is off by as much as 0.5 px maximum, it then should not matter that much

Comment: Yes, that should be accurate enough. It doesn't affect your simulation if the objects are displayed 0.5 pixels further to the left or right as long as the actual positions are accurate. You don't even have to round the numbers yourself, since pygame does that automatically for you when you pass them to `.blit` or assign them to a rect. Only some functions like `pygame.draw.circle` don't accept floats.

Comment: Thank you, this has really streamlined the progress of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I usually recommend storing the position and velocity of the game objects as [vectors](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) (which contain floats) to keep the physics accurate. Then you can first add the velocity to the position vector and afterwards update the rect of the object which serves as the blit position and can be used for collision detection. You don't have to convert the position vector to ints before you assign it to the rect, since pygame will do that automatically for you.

Here's a little example with an object that follows the mouse.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('steelblue2'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.direction = Vector2(1, 0)
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)

    def update(self):
        radius, angle = (pg.mouse.get_pos() - self.pos).as_polar()
        self.velocity = self.direction.rotate(angle) * 3
        # Add the velocity to the pos vector and then update the 
        # rect to move the sprite.
        self.pos += self.velocity
        self.rect.center = self.pos


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    font = pg.font.Font(None, 30)
    color = pg.Color('steelblue2')
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    player = Player((100, 300), all_sprites)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        txt = font.render(str(player.pos), True, color)
        screen.blit(txt, (30, 30))

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In simulation terms/accuracy wise, you should always keep your data as float. You should just round them, and cast them to int at the very point you are calling Pygame's functions that need integers.

Just do something like:

```
pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, (int(x), int(y), width, height))
```

for drawing a rectangle, for example.